# Spring + Thymeleaf. TH:ATTR append html tag

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My initial HTML Code looks like:

```
<select name="environmentSelect" id="environment" data-show-content="true" class="form-control">
    option>Environment</option>
    <option value="1"
         data-content="Test <span class='text-muted'>ONLINE</span><i class='fas fa-power-off text-success'></i>"></option>
    <option value="2"
         data-content="Dev <span class='text-muted'>OFFLINE</span><i class='fas fa-power-off text-danger'></i>"></option>
    <option value="3"
         data-content="Prod <span class='text-muted'>ONLINE</span><i class='fas fa-power-off text-success'></i>"></option>
 </select>
```

The environment names are taken from DB. So i wanted to populate them with th:attr

```
<select name="environmentSelect" id="environment" data-show-content="true"
                                class="form-control">
         <option>Environment</option>
         <option th:each="env : ${environments}" th:value="${env.name}"
              th:attr="data-content=${env.name} + '&lt;span class=\'text-muted\'>ONLINE&lt;/span&gt;&lt;i class=\'fas fa-power-off text-success\'&gt;&lt;/i&gt;'"
              th:text="${env.name}"
         ></option>
 </select>
```

The problem is, that when i open the developer console in chrome, i see the values and data-content, but the option stays empty. 
Can you please tell me, if there is a possibility to add html tags into the th:attr and if yes, how

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide HTML from browser console?

Comment: Also, I recommend not to build such complicated strings in Thymleaf pattern. Better to build it in Java code in some getter or put the built string into some additional model attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend not to build such complicated strings in Thymleaf pattern. Better to introduce special getter for it in DTO class

```
public class Environment {

    // .....

    public getDataContent() {
       return HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(this.name + " <span class='text-muted'>ONLINE</span><i class='fas fa-power-off text-success'></i>", "UTF-8");
    }

    // .....
}
```

And template

```
<select name="environmentSelect" id="environment" data-show-content="true"
                            class="form-control">
     <option>Environment</option>
     <option th:each="env : ${environments}" th:value="${env.name}"
          th:attr="data-content=${env.dataContent}"
          th:text="${env.name}"
     ></option>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've made like you've suggested but still cannot see anything.
The html code for an option:
```
<option value="102" data-content="DEV &amp;lt;span class=&amp;#39;text-muted&amp;#39;&amp;gt;ONLINE&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;i class=&amp;#39;fas fa-power-off text-success&amp;#39;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/i&amp;gt;"></option>
```

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad, i've forgot to add js dependency